# SQLite correct architecture vs performance

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design

I was wondering performance wise does creation and call to a table it self costs any performance?

I have a small table which will have about six columns and two rows. Problem is that from architectural point of view the table is in officiant there should be three tables with from two to three columns related via keys.

My dilemma is correct architecture vs performance but I have no actual understanding of performance the right architecture would take up.

P.S. The data from database will be retrieved only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with design over performance in this case. You will have more trouble if somehow your database scheme grows when you just have performance in your mind. Also I don't think that there will be any noticeable performance difference between your approaches.

Remember: Good design is better for maintainability.